# Replace first 5 non-space characters with *

Tags: java, substring, joptionpane

I was asked to replace the first 5 characters in any sentence inputted in JOptionPane, with asterisks. So I have this...

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Option {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String myName;
        myName= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a sentence");
        System.out.println(myName.substring
```

I just can't figure out how to isolate the first 5 characters in any sentence with spaces. Any help or hints on this would be great

Comment: You seem to have figured out that you need substring. What problem are you having with it?

Comment: Specifically, how to avoid replacing spaces with asterisks. Say the sentence input was "Hey how are you" I want the printed sentence to look like "*** **w are you" Im not sure what method I'm missing. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex, like this:

```
myName = myName.replaceFirst(".{5}", "*****");
```

`.{5}` is regex and means five characters.

EDIT: Since you needed to distinguish white spaces:

```
String tmp;
int lastCharIndex;
while(int i < 5) {
    if (!Character.isWhiteSpace(string.charAt(i)) {
        tmp += *
        i++;
    } else {
        tmp += " ";
    }
    lastCharIndex++;
}
tmp += myName.substring(lastCharIndex);
```

Comment: If I understood correctly, the first five characters should be replaced with asterisks but leaving whitespace untouched, which your solution fails to do. See his example in the comments.

Answer (score 0):

```
Character.isWhiteSpace()
```

This is a good method to use

```
String s = "Hi I am good";
String newString = "";
int count = 0

int i = 0;
while(count < 5){
    if (!Character.isWhiteSpace(s.charAt(i)) {
        newString += '*';
        count++;
        i++;
    } else {
        newString += string.charAt(i);
        i++;
    }
}

for (int i = count; i < s.length; i++) {
    newString += string.charAt(i);
}

System.out.println(newString);
// ** * ** good
```

Answer (score 0):

This solution is a bit longer but doesn't replace spaces with asterisks:

```
import javax.swing.*;
public class Option {
    public static void main (String[] args) {
        String myName;
        myName= JOptionPane.showInputDialog("Input a sentence");
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            if(myName.charAt(i) != " ") {
                sb.append('*');
            }
            else sb.append(' ');
        }
        System.out.println(sb.toString() + myName.subString(5));
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's more *simple* and *fast* if you use a loop for replace the desired characters. e.g.:

```
String input = "Hey how are you";
char[] chars = input.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0, j = 0; i < chars.length && j < 5; i++) {
    char ch = chars[i];
    if (!Character.isWhitespace(ch)) {
        chars[i] = '*';
        j++;
    }
}
String output = new String(chars);
System.out.println(output);
```

Output:

```
*** **w are you
```

Answer (score 0):

You could always implement a simple for loop with a condition inside like this:

```
int charCount = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < myName.length(); i++){
          if(myName.charAt(i) != ' '){
               myName = '*" + myName.subString(i);
               charCount++;
          }
          if(charCount == 5)
               break;
}
```